# Calculation of sensitivity and specificity from confusion matrix

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification

Consider a case where the number of labelled data as 0 = 1400 and labelled as 1 =100. The data labelled as 0 denote normal operating conditions and data labelled as `1` denote abnormal. An alarm is triggered only for abnormal events.

Assuming the following confusion matrix is obtained for the binary classification

```
cmMatrix = 

                    predicted 0  predicted 1
           truth 0    1100 (TN)      300 (FP)
           truth 1    30 (FN)         70 (TP)


cmMatrix = [1100,300;30,70];
acc_0  = 100*(cmMatrix(1,1))/sum(cmMatrix(1,:));
acc_1  = 100*(cmMatrix(2,2))/sum(cmMatrix(2,:));
```

will give `acc_0 =  78.5714` and `acc_1 =  70`

The confusion matrix is read as out of 1400 normal events, 1100 are correctly identified as normal and 300 are incorrectly identified as abnormal.
Then, out of 100 abnormal events, 70 are correctly detected as abnormal whereas 30 are incorrectly detected as abnormal.
I want to calculate the sensitivity and specificity for class 1 since that is of primary interest in abnormal event detection. This is how I did

```
Sensitivity = TP/(TP+FN) = 70/(70+30 ) = 0.70
Specificity = TN/(TN+FP) = 1100/(1100+300) = 0.78
```

- Sensitivity would refer to the test's ability to correctly detect abnormal events. Why is Sensitivity so low and different than accuracy `acc_1` which is so high (70%).
- Is this calculation correct and what is the difference between individual class accuracies and sensitivity?

Did I do any mistake in the calculation?

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @beaker: my confusion matrix was wrong and hence the person who answered could not catch the mistake in my calculations. This is the reason I kept asking under the comments. The answer may be outdated and not applicable. Is there a way to get a revised answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. I think the imbalance between sensitivity and specificity is what is confusing you, given your relatively high accuracy.  This is normal, and a common problem with classifiers especially when there is not an even split between the two classes. As a thought experiment, imagine that your classifier just arbitrarily decided that every sample was labelled. This would give you an overall 1400/1500 = 0.9333 accuracy, which might seem very good until you investigate the sensitivity and specificity, and it's all due to the difference in the size of the classes.

Because of this, and the misleadingly high accuracy when you have a very low sensitivity, it might be more representative to show the F1 score: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score

Comment: thank you for your answer. So what metric is considered to be safe to say that the classification is good? If there is few examples mislabelled (30) as 0 in my case as seen from the second row first column of the confusion matrix, I thought that the classifier did a good job. My criteria is that the classifier should miss less examples from the abnormal (class 1). Can you please elaborate on this point?

Comment: I also have a followup question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511959/matlab-help-in-interpreting-the-roc-curve-and-what-is-the-correct-approach It will be of immense help if you can  kindly take a look at it.

Comment: The metric you use will be dependent on your criteria.  I can't elaborate on your criteria, that is up to you.  You are saying that you want your positive class to be the labelled scores, so I would start by reformatting your confusion matrix to match that. Remember that accuracy looks at the entire percentage that is classified correctly, but whenever you talk about false negatives or sensitivity or anything like that it is all with respect to a certain class.  You may also want to look at this wikipedia article that lists different metrics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

Comment: My confusion matrix is constructed using `confusionmatrix` function in matlab. The first row is for class labelled as `0` and the second row is for class labelled as `1`.  Sensitivity score is with respect to the class labelled as `1`. I don't understand is it wrong?

Comment: There's nothing mathematically wrong with your confusion matrix.  But since the order you are interested in is reversed, reading it can be _confusing_  :)  Traditionally **True Positives** are in the top left corner of the matrix.  You can change the order when calling the confusionmatrix function in Matlab

Comment: My positive class is 0 which is the top row and the negative class is 1. But, I have calculated the sensitivity with respect to class 1. So TP = 70. I am now confused.

Comment: If you are trying to calculate the sensitivity with respect to class 1, then your positive class is class 1.

Comment: my confusion matrix was wrong. I had flipped the FP and FN. This is the reason I kept asking under the comments. The answer may be outdated and not applicable. Is there a way to get a revised answer?